# Linking a CSS file in HTML results in HTML5 video not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

Upon clicking the refresh button a random video from "Folder" should appear. This works well until I decide to integrate CSS via `<link rel="stylesheet" href="site.css" />` (The HTML file is site.html). Only a gray box appears and when inspecting it does show the source to be an mp4 file from "Folder" but does not show. Removing the CSS link allows it to work again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Generator</h1>
    </header>

    <main>
        <section>
            <article>
                <video height="800px" controls >
                    <source id="vsrc" />
                </video>
                <script>
                    document.getElementById("vsrc").src = "./Folder/" + Math.floor((Math.random()*266)+ 1) + ".mp4";
                  </script>
            </article>

            <article>
                <p><input type="button" value="Refresh" onClick="refresh(this)"></p>
                <script>
                    function refresh(){
                          window.location.reload("Refresh")
                        }
                  </script>
            </article>
          
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well how do we know what's inside that css file?

Comment: it's empty. Doesn't matter what's in it. Just linking it alone creates the problem

Comment: The only reason I see this happening is if the file contains some code that hides the video. Otherwise there's no real way this file is the issue, and you got something else completely broken. Maybe check the console for any errors?

Comment: Console doesn't show any errors